# What does "not supported" mean in Virtualbox?

Tags: virtualbox

I would like to connect my laptop's camera to a Linux guest (the host is Windows 10). I tried to do that though the settings of my virtual machine:

[image]

The status of the camera is `Not supported`. What does this mean? Not supported by Virtualbox or by the guest OS (Linux (Ubuntu 15.10) should support it, it is a basic camera)?

Comment: Unfortunately, across the industry, the phase "Not Supported" does not mean anything except "not my fault". Often there will be a distinction between "unsupported" and "not supported", but just as often they are synonymous. The issue is, that it can mean anything from "we haven't tested it but it will prolly work", to "yeah, theres one little problem with it when you hibernate" to, "this is a bad idea, but if you really need to", to "No, this will not work and we will stop you from doing it", to "this will murder your family, and destroy all your data." quite a range of meaning.

Comment: @FrankThomas: Thanks. I know what "not supported" can mean, in that specific case I was rather wondering about the "not supported by whom" (Virtualbox or the host VM)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That means that your virtual machine doesn't support USB port connection. Actually, you can't work with USB or COM connections in any virtual environment. You will have to use additional software.

Comment: Maybe these instructions will help you http://www.eltima.com/usb-in-virtual-machine/